# compiz crashing today

Tags: unity, compiz, 15.10

Running Ubuntu 15.10 32-bit under Parallels Desktop 11.

I the updater today, which included a new kernel.   After reboot the login screen comes up fine, but upon login, my desktop background and resolution updated, but no unity panel or other windows showed up.  Investigation revealed that compiz was segfaulting repeatedly and the window manager could not come up at all.

I attempted a re-install from scratch and the first thing I did after install was run updates -- same problem happened right away (though I could not 100% confirm it was compiz crashing because I neglected to install ssh-server before running updates -- but it "looked" the same visually.

Comment: Confirmed today the same crash happens on 64-bit.  Luckily, I learned about the "snapshot" feature of Parallels, so I can revert the machine to before the updates.

Comment: Confirmed today that the kernel update is not the problem.   I updated package-by-package, trial-and-error, until only the following package upgrades remain.   It all revolves around compiz.  Does anyone know if there is some special Parallels interaction with compiz?  The problem does not go away if I turn off 3D support.         compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default initscripts
  libcompizconfig0 libdecoration0 libnautilus-extension1a libunity-core-6.0-9
  lightdm nautilus nautilus-data unity unity-schemas unity-services
  unity-settings-daemon

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary workaround for the problem:

WARNING: this breaks some functions of parallels like coherence.
The workaround can be *reverted* by reinstalling the *parallels tools*.

> cd /usr/lib/compiz && sudo rm libprlcompiz_0_*

Compiz (used by unity) is crashing somewhere inside the plugin installed by parallels. Switch to a console and run "unity --replace --debug" for a backtrace. Seems to be an incompatibility caused by the latest updates.

Answer (score -2):

Confirmed that removing /usr/lib/compiz/libprlcompiz_* stops Compiz from crashing on my setup. I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit under Parallels 11 Mac.

I don't use Coherence, so that's not a big deal for me. Switching between fullscreen and multi-monitor, automatic mouse/keyboard grab, as well as clipboard sync all appear to be behaving just fine.
I didn't try modality, so I can't confirm whether or not it's broken, but I'm up and running as far as I'm concerned.